# In hive Decimal(10,4) is rounding off on insert into select

Tags: hive, decimal

When i do insert into a table1 select * from table2 ,it rounds up the values. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it will always round up if data type and length ( p,s) in table1 is less than table2. Pls make sure all data type and length are same or target is higher than source. Still, i would say, keep them same otherwise data load may fail with warning or produce abnormal values.